# Why does meta have a downvote option at all

Tags: discussion, feature-request, downvotes, voting

Recently I came across a few *opinion-based* questions like "should I answer questions if *blah blah*" on meta and noticed that some answers have been heavily down-voted and criticized, the thing is, opinion-based questions don't ***have*** answers and disagreeing with others should **not** result in being down-voted right?

Now, most questions on meta are somewhat based on personal opinion - including this one - so meta shouldn't even have a down-vote option, or down-voting should require much higher reputation or something similar.

Comment: Down-votes on meta don't actually contribute to reputation, and downvoting (at least for feature-requests) actually IS the way of showing disagreement.

Comment: @Pokechu22 if you don't agree, you comment why. down-voting means the answer is "clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Comment: If there is a way to express agreement, there should be an equal way to express disagreement. If there is a request where people agree on certain reason for disagreement, then repeating the comment or upvoting the comment doesn't give a good overview of how the community thinks about the request in general.

Comment: And the downvotes on this question mean that the answer to your question "opinion-based questions don't have answers and disagreeing with others should not result in being down-voted right?" is "Wrong.  Disagreement is indicated by downvoting.

Comment: I guess a lot of people _Disagree_ with me :P

Comment: +1 because the question "is useful and clear", as the tooltip specifies.  This implies nothing about agreement.  However, I also don't like to downvote to express disagreement, because it feels unfriendly.  Better to disagree by upvoting a better answer.

Answer (score 14):

"**meta shouldn't even have a down-vote option**"

Why?. Down-voting is used to express one's disagreement with another person's views. This doesn't necessarily prove that the other person is wrong, it just implies that people disagree with him/her.

"**down-voting should require much higher reputation or something similar.**"

*Reputation!=Knowledge*. Period. You can't ask opinions only from people with high rep (you are assuming only high rep people are smart). In SO everybody has the right to voice his/her opinion.

Answer (score -4):

Due to the multiple values of a down-vote, I would say it is a failure of the Stack Exchange system but is not limited to Stack Overflow Meta.

**Bad things they are used for:**

1. Down-votes are used as a way for some people to release their rage and anger at others (ie:  "I think your answer is so stupid or wrong that you deserve condemnation!").
2. Down-votes are used as a way to "attack" people whom you do not agree with (ie:  "In my life I was conditioned to dislike people who used examples like yours and therefor I dislike you! (down-votes)")
3. Down-votes are used to make someone stop responding (if they get enough negative results)
4. Down-votes are used to foster a culture of elitism (ie: "That doesn't meet *my* minimum standards" or "*I* don't trust the motivations of that poster")

**Good things they are used for:**

1. Expressing one's opinion
2. Identifying a question/answer is very poorly written
3. Identifying a question/answer may not be worth the time to even read
4. Identifying a question/answer that is not correct to such a degree that it should not be considered.
5. Identifying an answer which does not answer the original question to any discernible degree.

**Result:**
If enough people agree with someone's down-voting for ANY of the above reasons, that down-vote is maintained.  Regardless of whether it is truly arbitrary, hostile, non-objective, unreasonable, or outright wrong to draw that conclusion.

**The Other Result:**
People feel trolled, beat down, and may not ever get the answer that they seek and therefore remain ignorant; contradicting the goals of Stack Exchange.  They may even provide, what they thought was a good answer, but perhaps not the best and got attacked for it and may lead them not to answer other questions they may know the answer to out of fear of retribution.  The database that Stack Exchange is supposed to be, therefore, does not expand to provide greater value for visitors because of a lack of answers/questions that may be down-voted.  How?  The "elites" that find their way to the tops of these forums begin to judge, more harshly as they increase their reputations, that some questions are simply "beneath" them or are a "waste of time" or are simply against some answers people provide, not because they're objectively wrong, but because they don't like them.

The problem is, to 500 people scouring the internet on a given day looking for a simple and easy to understand answer to a simple question that may be slightly different from another question or answer, will find not only hostile elitism here, they will not find the simple answer they seek.  The answer they seek should conform to Stack Exchange's claims, but since that is manipulated by the "elites" and the "mobs" of people here; that goal is not met.

Sometimes answers will be down-voted because they don't use the proper nomenclature of the specific forum.  Unfortunately, not everyone seeking an answer to the question may sufficiently understand the nomenclature, further leading to people not being helped and a maintaining of the "elitism" of those who have the knowledge and those who do not.

Should Stack Overflow Meta have down-voting?  Maybe, maybe not.  Maybe if it didn't impact people's abilities to ask/answer questions it wouldn't be such a big deal, even on the Stack Overflow Meta forums.  One could simply express oneself regarding one's non-agreement or concerns.  The problem is people can be too flagrant with their down-voting at times and there's no real oversight.  Basically its a way to troll without consequences.

You never get down-voted for down-voting, so who cares if you were wrong in down-voting someone?  The system credits you for participating, you feel a rush, and there's no consequences to yourself.  Non-objective selfishness, release of emotions (such as anger), hostility, belittling, and alienation of someone else because of your "opinion"/"power" over them achieved!

It can work out to the same thing as if you were in a group at school and someone comes over to ask your group a question, then when you don't like the question, you can mock that "outsider" and make them feel bad for even approaching you.  Make them feel alone, make them "go away", while you laugh.  It's high school all over again.  Berate those who aren't in your clique.

Comment: your first "Bad things they are used for" is miss-identified. it's not *"rage and anger at [an]others"* if their answer is plain wrong and if someone's answer does something incredibly stupid like suggesting to run PHP's `shell_exec` with `rm -rf /` on web server to clear a caching system's cache, well yes that will clear the the cache but it will also wipe out everything else, both of these are quite worthy of a downvote

Comment: I don't see how I'm wrong, as it seems the example you gave falls under "Good, #4"; you were down-voting it due to it not entirely conforming to the answer to the question (except as an option that is explained including the warning you referenced) and in an attempt to prevent people from being harmed.  Sounds like a "good job" to me, on your part.

Comment: If someone downvote all of your post, that's called serial downvote and is unacceptable, a mod flag would take care of that.

Comment: Note that downvoting an answer costs a rep, so people often thinks very very carefully before downvoting an answer to see if it's actually wrong.

Comment: About the "nomenclature" you said about the Help Center contains all of the necessary information. It's unfair of you to say that.

Comment: @user202729 Only serial downvote if they catch it.  Not everyone considers the "cost" of downvoting in that context (which can be trivial). Nomenclature depends on which forum you're in.  The Help Center does NOT contain all necessary information for the given nomenclature for each forum.  Maybe this one, but not all others.