# Can the up and down vote buttons on Meta have the appropriate message attached to them?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, meta

There are a number of questions asking about downvoting on Meta and what it means.  Folk are frequently concerned about their valid, well thought out questions being downvoted as if they are "not researched and poor quality".

Just two examples of many...

[Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus?lq=1)

[Why does meta have a downvote option at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274635/why-does-meta-have-a-downvote-option-at-all?lq=1)

I think that part of the confusion is coming from the fact that the message associated with the voting buttons on Meta is the same as the message at Stack Overflow, but the meaning of the voting is not the same.

These buttons on Meta should have "I agree" or "I disagree" as part of their message - some wording to indicate that this is one of their uses

Comment: What about questions that don't show any research effort?

Comment: Then perhaps the tooltip text should be extended by a few words to indicate that they can also mean disagreement/agreement?

Comment: A similar request on MSE was declined earlier: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites

Comment: Interestingly it was highly upvoted, as were the supportive answers.   The "status declined" was not explained (as far as I can see).   Time has passed since then, and more questions have kept coming up showing peoples' confusion over what the votes on Meta mean.   Maybe now is the time?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Actually, it was explained. The third answer is from Jeff Atwood, one of the site's founders, and he had his reasons, which I can't say I agree with.

Comment: I didn't realise that was the official word.   In the time since then, based on what I've read here, I think that these _have_ become the official meanings (contrary to what he thought at the time) so it does seem time to review this.

Comment: Why do you think that we don't expect research and quality questions from people asking questions on meta? We do! Just because this is a meta site does not mean people are excused for not searching or for posting ranty/unclear/unspecific things.

Comment: I am not asserting that we don't expect quality questions.  What I am picking up on is the repeated discussions like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus  and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274635/why-does-meta-have-a-downvote-option-at-all  and ... many more.    In each, the answer is "downvoting means disagreement".   In each, the asker is confused whether their downvoted question is being accused of being low quality.   If downvote means "disagreement OR poor question", then it should say that.

Comment: It can also mean "lack of common sense" - at least I downvote for that reason a lot here on meta. A blanked "agree"/"disagree" like you propose would definitely be worse than the current options.

Comment: You're absolutely right.   I hadn't meant to suggest a blanket statement like that, and have edited accordingly

Comment: It doesn't take me an enormous mental jump to equate "not useful" to "I disagree".  Does it really?

Comment: @l4mpi - "common sense"? This is a public website. How is it you apply it here? Example?

Comment: @HansPassant: That jump isn't a correct one for everyone. If you're incredibly opinionated and closed-minded, then I suppose it's likely that anything you disagree with, you also consider "not useful". However, plenty of other people do see value and helpfulness even in things that they disagree with. If nothing else, bringing up an issue so that it is available for voting on can be helpful.

Comment: Well, thanks for that compliment.

Comment: I agree with this idea, but the arrow's telling me not to vote it up unless I can tell there's research (yes, jk; I upvoted).

Comment: :)  I moved some of the research from the comments into the question body!

Comment: @dandan78 Looks like just about no one agrees with Jeff on this.  I've never seen an answer downvoted that far before.

Comment: @animuson Care to explain why this was declined?  Consensus is that this question is correct, downvotes on Meta are different, and the various links indicate the vast majority of users who care want this change.

Comment: @Izkata Stack Exchange already declined this proposal [over on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites).

Comment: @animuson ... 3 years ago.   Time for a review?

Comment: @animuson Also look at the votes there.  It got vetoed _against_ the community's wishes.

Comment: @Izkata Because it's a horrible idea that will only further destabilize the voting culture of Meta.

Comment: @animuson [Please read the section entitled "Voting is different on meta"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).  You are long out of date.

Comment: @Izkata Trust me, I've read it. Try reading [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146051/how-should-we-vote-on-neutral-discussions/146057#146057) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227144). Changing the tooltip will just cause people to be more ignorant with their votes on Meta.

Comment: @animuson Possibly you should post an answer that says "It's a horrible idea that will destablize the voting culture", and in that answer explain why this is the case, then we could discuss that more easily under that answer than in the comments of the question, and people could vote and we'd see if there's broad agreement with your sentiment.  If describing what the vote means destabilizes things, maybe the meaning itself is a bit broken...

Comment: +1, because this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear! Hmm, but I disagree. Hmm, what to do... Wait I still agree...

Comment: this is older and both are almost same. I think the dupe should be reversed

Comment: I voted to close the questions in the other direction because the other one has a good answer. This one is older, but it doesn't have an answer. That is generally good practice when closing duplicates—pick the one with the best answers to use as the "master" question—but if I remember correctly, I fat-fingered it the first time, had to retract my vote and try again. @sagar

Comment: As the Q&A with a set of publicly visible answers is now finally open, I am voting to close this one as a duplicate of the [Can we edit/remove the arrows' tooltips on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337486/can-we-edit-remove-the-arrows-tooltips-on-meta).