# Is Meta Stack Overflow the place to provide Stack Overflow improvements suggestions?

Tags: support, questions, meta

I have a suggestion to improve the way we welcome new users.

Is SO meta the right place to 'ask' that kind of proposal as a question?

Comment: Sure it is. But make sure you aren't repeating something thoroughly trashed yet again. Or something just waiting to rise to the top of the (huge) heap of fully discussed suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. I there a specific way to search if my idea was already discussed by the community ?

Comment: Same mechanisms as in normal Stack for that. You use the search bar, you use google with a "meta.stackoverflow" filter, you use the related post bar, etc. For the fun of it, what's the FR?

Comment: Thanks @Patrice. So, here is my FR: "Why not offer a second chance to new users before they are massively downvoted?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294926/why-not-offer-a-second-chance-to-new-users-before-they-are-massively-downvoted

Comment: @remibecherard merci! Yeah honestly though, good chance there's a pushback on that one. The onus for posting good stuff is on the new users... we already have similar mechanisms I believe (I was never rate limited or banned so I can't say) but I do believe you get some kind of warning when your account is at risk of being question banned.  The big problem here is that new users outnumber old ones, so people don't have the time to take everyone by the hand and show them how this all works, relying on the automated system and goodwill of the new users

Comment: Protip: Read the [help] section to learn what a SE website is used for.

Comment: ok thank you alll! 
@Patrice: As tu visité le 2015 developper survey ?  https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015 
Seulement  ~800 devs pour le Canada comme pour la France !

Comment: A quick visit to the help menu might have helped. :-) See [What is Meta?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

- But make sure you aren't repeating something, already thoroughly trashed, yet again. Or something just waiting to rise to the top of the (huge) heap of fully discussed suggestions.
- Make sure you are familiar with the content of the help centre - be sure your assumptions about how it is supposed to work are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

But be aware: have very low expectations about your suggestion being implemented.

My experience (YMMV) is that the first thing that happens is that people here are suprisingly (to me)  resistant and negative about changing anything.

In addition, almost any opinion you (I, I guess) can form about "how things work" and "what would improve it" can draw remarkable counter arguments.  Get a big enough group together, and you're guaranteed to find a passionate disadvocate for anything.

And ... even when your idea [substantially](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274640/can-the-up-and-down-vote-buttons-on-meta-have-the-appropriate-message-attached-t) or [universally](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294563)
 popular, it is more than likely that nothing will happen.

Please don't read this as a complaint - it is just an observation and a caution to set your expectations suitably.

Comment: I added this answer separately to the other, rather than editing it in, because 1) the other was already accepted and this would substantially change it and 2) I definitely see this as a "different" answer.  But I'm sure there will be someone out there who disagrees ;)