# Why not offer a second chance to new users before they are massively downvoted?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, new-users

Often new users are massively downvoted after badly asked questions.

I think it could be fun to provide a new button-feature to redirect a new user to the "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for example ?

Accompanied by some extra explanations and a notice that they are viewing this message because their question doesn't fit the correct practices on the site.

This could be in the same direction that the popular [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users) meta question.

Comment: Votes should be based on what was posted and not the user who posted it.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that 1) new users will read these comments (which is quite unlikely since they already hit an interstitial that recaps the site's rules before posting) and 2) that users will stop downvoting after such comments are posted (which is unlikely because of human nature).

Comment: How to ask is already linked *from the page on which they wrote the question*. If they couldn't be bothered to read it then, tough.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, 1) I thought that most of them didn't the first time, but here the message would be adressed by a experienced user to a new one, that could be more eloquent. 2) ok. But at least, the experienced user that hit the button could do two things in one click : inform the new user and save its own time.

Comment: Why does this needs to be its own feature? Can't you just post a comment?

Comment: @Yannis I thought it could save time clicking a button instead of wrinting each time the same things..

Comment: I think a personalized comment has a lot more chances of getting through.

Comment: @JoeW Of course the votes should be based on the posts instead of the user who posted it. I dont get what this has to do with the question though.

Comment: @Loko Because when you base the votes on the post instead of the user it doesn't matter if they are a new user with 1 rep or an experienced user with lots of rep.

Comment: Well, a second-chance would extend the lifetime of the bad users and so reduce the number of new, anonymous accounts being raised to circumvent the question-bans.  This might reduce the load on the SO servers/DB.   As a bonus, the second-chance might occasionally persuade new users to improve their question/s, though I admit that's a very unlikely outcome.

Comment: New users agree to take the [tour] when creating an account and given links to the [help] with a clear suggestion that they spend some time there. How many more chances to learn how the site works do they need? They've ignored the offers to do so already a couple of times. They also ignore lists of previous similar questions that are presented to them and post duplicates anyway. How many chances is enough? New users have access to the help center and many examples of existing good questions to use as guidelines before posting.. There's nothing *special* about new users. We all started there.

Comment: @JoeW I think the OP is talking about more guidance for the 1 rep people (or just low rep) who get downvoted a lot. I dont see him anywhere stating that he doesn't want the users to be downvoted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shortcuts to help pages are already provided:

> [help], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior] and [meta-help] – link to frequently visited pages of the help center. Link text is "help center" (capitalization is respected). All links point to the main site.

See the [Advanced Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) page for details.