# Hostility level of communities within SO are varied. Can we make it better?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

In Stack Overflow, I have entered different communities. What I mean by community is more like the tag given in a particular question. ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), etc.) Community hostility level are varied. Some are friendly while others are hostile.

For newcomer, I usually welcome them regardless of the community. But some users have no tolerance for such a stupid question. And this only affects certain communities, not all. Some communities are very gentle and welcoming.

A newcomer came to the site, they were still new and fragile. And they were just kicked out of the community straight away. With reputation below 100, and people have a tendency to downvote a question and demoralize. These newcomers need to be guided, they need to have some basic confidence that SO is actually a good place to get help.

How can we make each of these communities healtier, so that newcomers are not so afraid and demoralized, and instead give them confidence?

Comment: While we want to be friendly, that does not mean we need to accept each and everyone regardless of how ignorant or conforming they are to our **quality guidelines**. Some communities see more low-quality influence than others and are more or less jaded and/or time constrained. The idea really should be to not have "communities" at all, just an accumulation of **high-quality content**.

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping anyone try to make their suggestion as an answer. so we could comment on the particular suggestion. And possibly improve from that.

Comment: If you have the time and patience then you are most welcome to assist the newbies. A lot of them put in virtually zero effort before spewing their question out, so be prepared to have to work hard.

Comment: Hostility is a personal opinion. What do you define as "hostile" ? On that note: claiming hostility is also often a personal excuse to not have to admit a mistake.

Comment: This topic has been discussed to death many times already. StackExchange have put a lot of effort into help resources, but you simply can't make people read and obey. People also have the mistaken belief that just because they understand the question they asked, everyone else should understand it too, and it's our fault if we don't.

Comment: @Gimby Hostility, can be in the form of "Downvote" for user having reputation 1. Because This user just starting to crawl.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the reputation of the user is. If the content they posted is undesirable, we **vote on the content.** Not on the user. Are you proposing we adopt a sliding scale approach instead of clearly defined rules?

Comment: @deceze Yes, but these new user, have no idea how they could make a good question

Comment: My first question is completely rubbish. I have a problem, but I don't know how to describe my problem. because I'm still new. and worst get demoralize

Comment: They should have common sense, and every user is directed to [ask] when asking questions -- which quite well summarises what is expected.

Comment: Then they'll have to learn how to formulate a good question. Sorry, but that's the least they can do, really. That's sort of a universal skill, not even tied to your technical prowess. If you can't even express clearly enough what you want to a stranger then maybe you shouldn't be posting in a public forum (as if that has ever stopped anyone, haha).

Comment: "Yes, but these new user, have no idea how they could make a good question" - by the time you ask a question, you've been told how to ask a good question. Please don't blame other people for some people's laziness in not reading material they're presented with.

Comment: We have the RTFM mindset, because we are developer.  But newcomer might not know. We could write down an instruction told them to read, but if you imaging newcomer would rather ask in some other platform such as Facebook Group, which is more welcoming to a stupid question.

Comment: And the final outcome, their problem is solved from the Facebook Group which is more friendlier people. And you notice, facebook group, has no RTFM. People just post anything they don't know about that particular topic.

Comment: Here are yesterday's contributions to this long-running waste of time: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294939/3001761, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294926/3001761 - *"newcomer would rather ask in some other platform such as Facebook Group, which is more welcoming to a stupid question"* that's fine, but that group will have the same problem attracting experts to *actually answer* the questions that SO was designed to solve

Comment: Then let them ask on Facebook @Yeo. Once they realize they aren't getting any useful answers, they'll be back.

Comment: the hostility is everywhere, down votes for a perfectly fine question, I'm getting fed up with that.

Comment: I'm just giving an example. (I don't literally mean only Facebook, it could be Google Group, iRC, Mailing List, Skype, Slack, etc.). These community are starting to be more useful in getting a trivial problem solved or simple error. and get juniors move on to the next stuff.

Comment: @Yeo Great, so there are already places for the stuff that doesn't belong here, and as you say it's becoming more useful. So what's the problem? Why does every site have to be everything to everybody?

Comment: I'm just seeing that a complete beginner becoming more hopeless in SO. So, I have no problem if SO doesn't accept such a triviial question. Perhaps the core value of SO is slightly different from what I value.

Comment: One second, and two clicks, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393841/what-is-callback-function-and-where-it-is-implemented-and-what-is-the-difference
IIRC, I myself have already answered one question like this, and Googling 'What is callback function' gives: 'About 1,890,000 results'.   I can feel the hostility rising...

Comment: @MartinJames I'd rather have that question unvoted, rather than downvoted. :'(

Comment: @Yeo then don't vote on it, but you don't get to tell others how to vote. I suspect the downvotes on this question are because it's asked, in one form or another, *pretty much every day*, so regular contributors are a little tired of wheeling out the same arguments you couldn't be bothered to search for.

Comment: @Yeo if I see a crap post, I will downvote it regardless if the member is a newbie or not. You never have a say in how I vote. Don't like it? Tough luck.... which reminds me, time to use my 40 votes (most are usually downvotes).

Comment: @Yeo There you go, I posted 3 different variations you can vote on...

Comment: @Vincent Which "perfectly fine question" do you see getting downvotes?

Comment: @TZHX this one for starters

Comment: @Vincent Sorry, I meant do you have an example of a *good* question that was getting undeserved down-votes on SO. I thought that was clear. Voting on meta is different -- you should learn this. [meta-help]

Comment: @TZHX i guess there are many of those, especially on a personal attack on a particular user.

Comment: You may guess about the existence of such posts, but typically these sorts of discussions are helped by concrete examples. I don't see any evidence whatsoever of personal attacks happening routinely against new users.

Comment: @Yeo Why do you think anything is a *personal attack* on anyone? Do you have evidence for that? Voting on the quality of a user's posts is not the same as "attacking the user personally".

Comment: @deceze, or perhaps it could be another reason. But I'm not sure why sometime a perfectly correct answer or solution get get downvoted. I have a feeling that I might have triggered offensive comment on the question. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30005117/764592.

Comment: Maybe it was down-voted for being a code-only answer that doesn't help anyone but the person asking the question? Trying to assume the intentions of voters isn't productive if they don't tell you. Taking it as a personal attack is certainly the wrong way to handle it.

Comment: @TZHX Maybe, but I believed it doesn't matter, because it's just a trivial question and also the OP has its problem solved.

Comment: SO is supposedly about creating a quality repository of knowledge, not solving trivial code issues for individuals that will help absolutely no one else.

Comment: @Yeo the site does not go by your rules

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403935/code-not-calculating-correctly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403869/trouble-using-fscanf-to-read-coordinates-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403678/callback-function-vs-ordinary-function-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403612/whiles-t-is-equivalent-to-which-expresion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403538/double-free-or-corruption-error-when-deleting-first-node-of-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403270/do-macros-run-faster-than-global-variables-in-c-how-to-change-macros-between-ru

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402654/how-sorting-an-array-of-strings-comparing-an-specific-string-by-c-program

Comment: Feeling hostile yet?  I could keep this up, but it's pointless because the bad questions arrive faster than I can post links to them

Comment: *such a stupid question* - How can you expect to garner sympathy when even *you* are referring to the questions as stupid? You just sank your *own* battleship.

Answer (score 27):

> My first question is completely rubbish. I have a problem, but I don't know how to describe my problem.

My first question was complete rubbish as well. But for different reasons. SO was a new thing back then, still in beta. "Questions and answers" was something of a new concept back then when mailing lists and PHP web forums ruled. I treated SO as yet-another-forum with that first question. And back then it didn't even get much of a reaction at all, since nobody was using SO.

But, fast forward 7 or 8 years and SO is *the* established player in this space. Nobody can have any excuse not to understand "Q&A" these days. There's a ginormous eco system around SO with tons and tons of material and intros and help centres dedicated to explaining to newcomers what a Q&A is and how to post decent questions. There's tons of precedent now on this site with millions of questions asked and answered. There simply is no excuse to not understanding even the basics of what makes a good, answerable question.

If you cannot explain your problem clearly, then I don't know if there's any value in your posting it publicly, anywhere. Even a <del>more welcoming</del> community with lower standards will hardly be able to properly help you unless you can express what you want.

Yes, the bar has been raised somewhat, but we cannot lower it. SO's core value is **high quality content**. If we do not keep that core value SO will become useless for its core mission: providing a resource for common problems and their solutions. Not for getting *your* problem answered mind you, for being able to *find* existing solutions to problems. We can't budge on that core principle just to make some new users feel more welcome, sorry.

Also see [Downvotes are taken so damn personal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/476).

Comment: I even answered a question on SO without having the remotest clue what it was (April 2012). I see lots of people expect it to be a "forum" or expect any "question" (it has a qiestion-mark, explicit or not, so it's a question) to be one demanding an answer. So new people who don't know this do need to be enlightened on it. This won't happen with five instant downvotes and snarky comments.

Comment: Snark should indeed be left out of it. But again, the guidelines have crystallised over time and are written down and available to anyone in various forms all over the place now. We *do* try to enlighten people before they even post their first word. If they still fail to get that, we still *do* need to enforce the guidelines we set up. I don't see how *not* downvoting helps anyone.

Comment: I'm not arguing (in this instance) for not downvoting, or (ever) for mandatory comments on downvotes. This issue doesn't go away, so currently *something* isn't working, so just sticking to guidelines doesn't move the issue forward. I know from your other answer, you're not suggesting that it is set in stone. My initial comment was to counter the idea that everyone knows what SO is and everyone knows what a Q&A is in SO terms, rather than Yahoo Answers's terms.

Comment: I see now, fair enough. The question really is (and has been broad up before): is SO's mission still up-to-date (I think *yes*), and is the way to enforce that mission still workable (I think SO is hitting scaling problems). However, I have no idea what the alternative to enforcing the guidelines would be. If you have any practical idea, I'm all ears.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm also all ears. What prompted me was OP's point about differential treatment across tags. On the low-volume tags I attend, we have more time to deal with "deficient" questions. Different case in high-volume tags, where the amount of time just to sort things to a reasonable state could be demoralising for those who set out to attempt. I'm not saying there are simple answers, but I do think there are not simple statements of the response to the issue, especially with differential responses in tags, for some of the reasons you set out on the other answer.

Comment: I can see why that's an interesting point, but it just boils down to the same old "how to make things better". It doesn't really matter that things aren't so bad in some tags vs. others; we simply want the bad tags to become better, for which we do not have a solution.

Comment: Yes, moved on to your third answer now.

Comment: "Even a more welcoming community will hardly be able to properly help you unless you can express what you want" - grmbl grmbl grmbl. That mildly implies that the SO community is less welcoming.

Comment: @Gimby FTFY. :-)

Answer (score 16):

> A new comer came to the site, <...> With *Reputation below below 100*, and people have a *tendency to downvote a question and demoralize*. These newcomers, need to be guided, they need to have some basic confidence that SO is actually a good place to get helps.

You seem to be under the impression that newcomers get downvoted *because* they're newcomers.

This isn't the case.

Newcomers that get downvoted, get downvoted because they're posting low quality questions or answers. Often, their questions lack critical information or formatting and punctuation, answers don't answer the question, only contain code, or are in some other form completely unclear.

Low quality / bad questions is the reason (a portion of the) newcomers are getting downvoted. It's got nothing to do with the rep they have at that moment. (And it shouldn't)

If a newcomer has a basic understanding of the English language, *and* knows how to search before asking, that person can contribute to SO, or anywhere in the SE network, without any problems.

Comment: It is good that you think of it that way, and this world will be in perfect condition if everyone think rationally. But community isn't just one to vote. In fact most people didn't think rationally and have a bias. Imagine you are given a sentence: A: "Intelligent-industrious-impulsive-critical-stubborn-envious" vs B: "envious-stubborn-critical-impulsive-industrious-intelligent". B seems to be more negative then A. but they are just Bias.

Comment: Quibbling over the reason for the downvotes/comments side-steps the issue of demoralisation and the final sentence you quote.

Comment: @BillWoodger: Fair enough, but in my opinion newcomers don't need more guidance. Frankly, I don't see the problem in demoralizing users that post questions without a _tiny_ bit of research. (Stuff like _"How do I remove x elements from an array"_)

Comment: OK, but *this is going to happen, what are we going to do about it?* If the answer to that is "keep everything asis", then it's all easy. It'll continue to be like trench warfers, with tens of thousands of newbies massacred by machine-gun and artillery. *After* they post a question is when we know that they don't know how to ask here (for whatever reason). Then you get the seasoned soldier, who knows next time, and the time after, to ask a good question. Sorry, go to stop now. I think I can see a sniper.

Comment: I do as you suggest, and more, and still get down-voted.

Answer (score 11):

Alternative answer to my rather "negative" previous one:

Communities vary widely due to the nature of the people participating in them. Some tags like [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) are pretty much literally inundated with crap day in day out, because PHP is a very popular language with an extremely low bar to entry which attracts tons of new users. By sheer necessity there's a higher volume in questions and because of that necessarily also a higher amount of crap (not even taking into account that the percentage of quality content may or may not vary from other tags). [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) simply isn't your friendly neighbourhood mom-and-pops, it's a giant undertaking. It's understandable that people may have a much shorter fuse there than in other low-volume tags.

Other communities, like, say, [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell), a) see a lower amount of traffic due to the language being much less popular and b) typically have a higher expectation for quality content due to Haskell appealing a lot to more scientific types. While [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) will entertain most trivial questions as long as they aren't utterly incomprehensible, you'll probably have to try a little harder yourself in [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell). On the other hand, you *may* get a little more in-depth rebuttal in [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) than you'd get in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), where the routine is *downvote, move on*.

Other communities may have other standards yet, it really depends. And that's simply a reality. Everyone deals with what they're seeing according to the realities. Super-high-traffic tags simply *cannot* hold everyone's hand individually. Super-specialised tags expect a certain minimum of complexity to even make it worth answering.

You can try to appeal to everyone to be nice, but unless you truly understand why things are the way they are this will probably not be of much use. If you have a good practical idea for how to make it better, by all means, tell us. We're wondering that ourselves.

Comment: This one I can go for. Now there's just resolving the big in the last pararaph... anyone seen Solomon around?

Comment: I can't really because I rebel against the notion that individual programming languages/platforms break down into isolated communities. They do not, there is only the subset of the larger programming community sharing the services of the SO website.

Comment: @Gimby Theoretically yes, and I dislike the moniker "community" as well; I'm just sticking with it based on the OP's nomenclature for the sake of discussion. In practice though there *are* distinct groups on SO. While there is *some* overlap, sometimes a *large* overlap, between different tags, there are also tags which have very few users in common. And since certain programming languages also come with their own culture and way of thinking, that often makes those tags very distinct.

Comment: I think we can say it like this: whether communities exist or not, it makes no difference. They should and must not influence in any way how SO is used within said "communities". The only thing the distinctness of tags you mention should influence is in the determination if something is off-topic or not.

Answer (score 9):

Third take: [**lurk moar**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lurk%20moar).

It behooves anyone to familiarise themselves with the community they're going to enter before they do so. Otherwise they'll get hazed to varying degrees in order to indoctrinate them. It works the same way everywhere in life. The standards SO demands really aren't spectacular. If a new users cannot even muster that, they simply need to *lurk moar*.

Comment: I like this also.  Is SO mature enough to say "we don't need bags of crap, we outweigh that with good content"? So we *make it more difficult to ask a question*. Privilege gained at, say, 10-15, to get "normal" asking. How to make it difficult (not just clicking on "yes I understand") is the tricky part :-)

Comment: I don't know what became of this (didn't attend MSE much after the split): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216683/what-happens-to-new-users#. In any business, keeping new customers so they become repeat customers is important. In this "business", because the "customers" provide their value in content, and because there is some content that is not wanted, and some that is, it seems futile to smash a new customer to pieces when over the coming years they may otherwise provide a number of good-to-stellar questions.

Comment: Interestingly there's very little difference between come-backers and stay-aways regardless of what negative things happened to their question. That suggests that keeping the system free of crap has no averse effect on the number of customers.

Comment: The stats are (or were) too raw and undifferentiated for any reasonable interpretation, but the question itself is interesting (and being sourced from SE perhaps has a slightly different rationale). Some re-working of this research could indicate whether, by behaviour, new users are demoralised/scared away as an objective measure, rather than the subjective thing we see with concerned individuals raising the issue often. Does Action A or Action B work better? If we stick to "we do Action A" based on faith (we have rules) then we may be right, or wrong.