# Why is this unclear question with no minimal reproducible example or error messages good?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8781180) audit and while I understand that once in a while bad question get in the audits and that steps are taken to improve this, I still may have missed something that could explain to me how this question can be remotely considered good, except for the fact that 7 passing-by people wished to vote for it.

From [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818920/mediaplayer-in-fragment-tab-android#comment50305337_30818920) comment, those votes can also have been attracted by a bounty on that question.

Why it's bad:

- Moderately huge code block, far from a minimal, reproducible example
- errors are mentioned, yet no error messages are present in the question
- the question was edited, linking to a contradictory statement that in fact there was no error messages, but that link is dead
- the question statement is `But there are errors on getIntent() , getMenuInflater() and finish();`. As far as unclear questions go, this is not useful in any way to answer it.

**Have I missed something?? Is it in fact a ruby that my cynical mind just do not want to see?**

the worst part is I knew an hour before flagging as off-topic I would be failing an audit, and later ranting about it on meta, but I won't let a machine coerce me into accepting this as a good answer.

Comment: I really would suggest a dev takes a look at the voting taking place on these kind of questions. You start to think that an army of upvote bots is patrolling the android tag....

Comment: Reason I suggest that is [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299026/578411) of a couple of days back.

Comment: @rene this also makes me think of this older meta about varying 'hostility' levels in different communities: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294994/hostility-level-of-communities-within-so-are-varied-can-we-make-it-better . Perhaps within the android tag the "community" has evolved into an unhealthy 'being nice' upvoting tendency.

Comment: If you strongly suspect a bad audit but don't feel like voting against the way you know it should be, just hit Skip.

Comment: Very wise as always @Nathan. I guess I should stop acting with such contradicting emotions... But I'm happy that the question is now out of audits, even it it meant for me to fail one. I think next time I'll skip it after raising a flag asking for it to be removed from audits.

Comment: I can confirm the Android tag is full of dolts ;)

Comment: It's a terrible question with no redeeming social virtue.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your VTC was correct; the audit was a poor one.

- The question is incomplete, missing out on key details like error messages.
- The answers and advice, however well-intentioned, are more or less stabs in the dark (just look at the discussion between the OP and Blackbelt, which went back and forth for hours).
- There was never a resolution, nor did the OP post one, assuming he ever figured it out. And since any fix relies on the OP's specific code (partially unavailable behind broken links), it's unlikely someone will stumble along and provide a correct answer. Or find it remotely useful.

The question should've been closed as off-topic originally. Now it's closed/deleted.

Comment: I'm very relieved that community's action towards the question was so fast, I actually wasn't expecting as much.