# Is this question about an error in an IDE really good enough to be a review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I was given [an audit in Triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392382/) today. I thought it over and decided it was debugging help. The question showed an error occurring while running an application; there was no code. I don't understand why this is considered a good enough question to be an audit.

I'm not an expert with the platform; actually if you were to sit me in front of Xcode or anything iOS I'd stare at it like a dog finding a mirror. And it's been brought up in a meta post to try to look at questions from tags you have preferred. I've also seen the suggestion to open every question in a new tab, and look through it there, to find out audits.

Given that, what should I have done with this audit? Should I have just skipped it because of not knowing the technologies?

Comment: "My question is what I should have done with that audit instead. Should I have just skipped it because of not knowing the technologies?" Yes. If you're not familiar enough with the technology to judge the post, skip.

Comment: "I even keep doing reviews while sitting under the knowledge that once I slip up the next time I'll get 16 days and then a permanent review ban." - Where did you read that? As far as I know [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344967/424903) is the truth.

Comment: I pretty much agree, but some tags seem to have communities that feel general rules of SO do not apply to them, and upvote en masse stuff for reasons other people can't fathom. In most sane tags (assuming such a thing exists) that would be closed, as it literally lacks every part of an acceptable question.

Comment: @S.L.Barth in this case, it's arguably a dump of error message. It's not really related to programming, in any way that is evident from the text itself.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Unless I'm mistaken, in the Triage queue knowing the technology is a lot less important than knowing how the flags are used. You can't expect 500-rep users to find every dupe, and deciding between the Triage options is very different from deciding what vote to cast.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The problem occurs in Xcode, an IDE. If the problem is specific to Xcode, then it is on-topic.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'd argue that configuring one's IDE for any options is not necessarily on topic. EG the criteria is not "it happens in an IDE". There are off topic questions that are specific to an IDE.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier If the error message in that question is specific to Xcode, then IMO the question is on-topic. If it is a general Apple problem, it might be better suited for [Apple.SE]. I would have liked to see more research effort in the question, though.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Fair enough.

Comment: Yeah guess I'll just stay out of queues for thirty days or forever. Thanks for the replies

Comment: Why was this reopened? Also thanks for the edit @JoshCaswell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This belongs to a certain class of Stack Overflow question. Sometimes a programming tool, especially a brand-new version*, malfunctions inexplicably. (Depending on the tool,) there may not be a lot of information to go on -- we may even be reduced to the level of our non-technical friends and family...*"I dunno, it just stopped working"*.

On their faces, these may not be good-looking questions. But they are valuable**, given that **lots** of people are likely to encounter the problem. (And thus the upvotes.) They are small, and succinctly answerable. They are in many ways the meat and potatoes of Stack Overflow: You Google the stupid error message your fluffing IDE is spitting out *now*, argh!, and find a quick resolution. You might have to try two or three of the answers. You might even have to learn something. But often, you get it fixed on the first try, and get back to work.

It's understandable that you would look at one of these and think *"low information, no-effort error dump -- thumbs down"*.† But there may be a broader context and a need to consider *"What did I do the last time I was in the same situation? Did I find a solution in a question like this? Is this one a clear and findable problem statement? If I were searching, would I be able to recognize it as being my problem too?"*

And, as other people have said, if you're way out of your area of expertise, just skip the review.

---

*And especially Xcode

**As long as there's a good answer, at least. One problem with these questions is that they also attract lots of "restarting the IDE/machine/universe fixed it for me!" answers over the years.

† It may very well be that this particular instance isn't the one we'd really *like* to keep; maybe somebody wrote up the problem better, so that it's got more information that makes it a bigger search target.

Comment: Hmmm... valid explanation, I'm a bit less bothered by this. Honestly, I feel a blurred feeling of abuse of the system when I see questions such as these, but I guess it's ok... It's just that the line is very fine between these questions and lazy error dump questions, and the difference is mostly the votes on it. To make it worse, these votes pile up on tags that are relatively known to [upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299184) utter crap randomly, such as android or ios. All in all, I think I'll just go take a coffee and stop thinking about this.

Comment: I don't mean to assert that the votes are _necessarily_ an indicator of quality, @FélixGagnon-Grenier; they're a natural consequence of this kind of question, and I think the score probably does get overinflated. I would agree with you about the fine line, and I think the question still has to be judged on its own merits. I just wanted to say that the merits may be a little broader than they may appear at first blush.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. I could not have said it better myself. If Meta had bounties, I would award this one.