# Notice when downvoting a new users question

Tags: discussion, downvotes, new-users, welcoming

So recently, we've been seeing a lot of discussion around Stack Overflow [not being very welcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). There are two questions that proposed an approach to handle downvotes on new users, both massively downvoted:

1. [Why not offer a second chance to new users before they are massively downvoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294926/why-not-offer-a-second-chance-to-new-users-before-they-are-massively-downvoted)
2. [Is downvoting new users a barrier to Stack Overflow's growth?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296037/is-downvoting-new-users-a-barrier-to-stack-overflows-growth)

I'll take this shot anyway.

**First of all:**

I agree that limiting downvotes is a bad idea, and that bad questions are bad questions, no matter what. Bad content needs to be downvoted, period.

**But:**

Downvotes are a heavy measure, and - sadly - rarely followed by a helpful comment. This needs to change, at least for new users. When a *new* user asks a bad question, he might not know about site politics or how things work around here. Sure, we've got [a new, shiny question wizard](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/06/21/rolling-out-the-welcome-wagon-june-update/) now, but there might be more ways to deal with bad content by new users better.

**My proposal:**

When a user downvotes a new users question (first question, etc.), a warning appears, just like when you try to vote on your own question. It says something along the lines of: "This user is new, consider helping them out". 
**The downvote will still be counted.**

The message might look like this:

[image: user question with message]

**What do you think about this approach? Is there anything I've missed?**

Feedback is very welcome.

Comment: Have you also read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Comment: I am not saying feedback should be mandatory, but a little warning that the user might not be very experienced sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: I downvoted *this* question because I consider the proposal made here to be not useful.

Comment: The trouble is, we've all read your proposal hundreds of times before in slightly different forms posted by others. FWIW you've actually referenced some other questions which does make you a cut above most other posters.

Comment: My reasons to vote on a question are my own. I don't care where the user is on the scale of _"Just registered"---"Jon Skeet"_. A popup like this would only be a nuisance.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree with that. But we should all be aware that "are my own" will soon no longer be a valid reason.

Comment: @LutzHorn: I wish Stack Overflow good luck policing (down)vote reasons, then. That's impossible.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree that voting cannot be regulated nor should it. As described in the comments on Lutz's answer, this question is not about the voting itself, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus The have Machine Learning Magic™ to know your reasons. If you are not nice and welcoming they will know.

Comment: Since when did down-voting become "unwelcoming"? I thought the comments were "unwelcoming"? It is not the duty of the down-voter to leave a comment explaining why they down-voted.

Comment: Actually such a proposal would lead me to comment even less.... If I spot the user is a new one, I know commenting will lead to lashing out, insults, pushbacks, and rarely an improved post.

Comment: Better: 'This account is new, consider not helping them out and, instead, move on to the next question that may be a better use of your  limited time to handle'.

Comment: @GBlodgett Some people are going to focus on the content, not the user, when looking at a post.  And they're not necessarily wrong to do so.  If someone has considered how a given post can be improved, I certainly don't see it as important for them to check the user card before providing that useful information.  It's very unlikely to change the desirable responses.

Comment: I agree with the OP tho. The current policy is not balanced. It only favors the answerer and it does not take account of the newbie's perspective. If a newbie gets a downvote without a sufficient explanation, how can one improve?

Comment: why is this [info/guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) or [this one](https://borngeek.com/2016/09/26/a-new-users-guide-to-stack-overflow/) is NOT placed in "Ask a question" process/button ? A quick read should at least make the 1st time user be very mentally (& resource/research wise) prepared. /(-_-)'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, and I wish that users would stop suggesting that SO curators spend yet more volunteer time on sub-prime questions from new accounts instead of handling good questions from anyone.

A new 'Member for today' account with 1 rep does not guarantee a new user.  It could be a ban-evasion account, a spammers' 1001st account, link 34 in a voting ring, a freshly-knitted sock puppet or a homework-dumper one-per-week burner account.  New account != new user.

Many, many new accounts post bad questions, and I don't want to engage with those users. There is next-to-no upside in doing so. It invites less-than-welcoming exchanges, rude and abusive replies that I cannot defend myself from.  No, mods etc. cannot help because there is no effective sanction that can be applied to 1-rep accounts whose users can just open more of if banned/suspended.

The track record of users improving their questions already sucks. Help efforts are usually a futile waste of effort, submerged under the tsumami of 'WHERE IS MY ANSWER?  I WANT MY ANSWER NOW'.

I don't want to provide dedicated help to new accounts, not even a closing click on a message box, but I would surely not impede those who do, such as, (presumably), yourself.  As I've often suggested before, all those users who suggest more help for new accounts could easily set up a chatroom, to which links to the bad questions can be posted.  Then, those like yourself who think that new accounts need help can respond as you wish to the thousands of links per day.  The rest of us can just forward them.

WIN-WIN!

Comment: Well, umm..  I didn't expect an accept out of my answer!  Not complaining, but it's been a long time:)

Comment: This is a great answer, but I still think people should give reasons for their downvotes when downvoting a new user's question. Not necessary to make it compulsory, but have a tooltip that says "please explain the reason for your downvote"

Comment: Perhaps stop downvotes from someone's first question.It is discouraging for the genuine new users; perhaps helpful comments or constructive close votes should be the norm for a new users. At the end of the day it is easy to see such a downvote as arrogant and lazy.

Comment: @PeterSmith it is not possible to discriminate between a genuine new user and yet another homework burner account, sock puppet etc.

Comment: @PeterSmith Unfortunately a lot of new users come here with wrong expectations and react poorly to comments. If new users see downvotes as arrogant and lazy, in most cases a helpful comment wouldn't change that (speaking from experience).