# A LIKE button - collecting useful feedback even from users not having account/reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

I find a lot of answers really useful and I do use them a lot.
However I don't have enough reputation (or I may not be logged in).

I suspect that there must be many like me.

If so, having a "Like" button (in addition to the voting button) will help us to give the feedback (this doesn't care if the answer is rigorous, relevant to the question asked, well-formatted etc. , just that it was useful to my situation, so I want to leave a trace of my gratitude).

Maybe this already exists, in which case I shall remove this post!

Comment: Nooooo! Stack Overflow isn't workin like frickin' Facebook.

Comment: This sounds very social to me which is not the kind of thing we want to achieve here. If posts are marked/voted/liked it should be to some degree a reliable measure for post quality. I don't see how anonymous users can be trusted to know what a quality post is.

Comment: That is exactly what upvoting is for. [The bar is even set pretty low.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: would there be a dislike button?

Comment: @KevinB does facebook already have one?

Comment: so what? we have a like-privilege that unlocks at 1 and gives what? half rep? Why not just drop the 15 points limit for upvotes if we're at that point.... (not that I'm for dropping the 15 points limit)

Comment: @rene no idea, I avoid it like the plague.

Comment: "_However I don't have enough reputation_" ah so that's the reason for a new kind of upvote.  It only takes 15 rep to upvote.

Comment: Guys, we already have this feature.

Comment: I wonder if Wikipedia gets spammed with "you should become facebook" feature requests. Or is SO just giving these people the wrong impression

Comment: Quite appropriate, [voting on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274640/2564301) *does* work just like Like/Dislike thumbs. The best part is where you don't have to mentally work out the net difference, because it's shown by default.

Comment: As I said, I use lot of things from internet.. and from stackoverflow. I thought it will be appropriate to express my gratitude as a feedback. I guess I have to use them and not let them know that I used it...c'est la vie I guess :).

Comment: small clarification to what i had in mind: basically quality [soundness, well presented, well researched, relevant to the question, etc.] and usefulness [situation specific, hack, maybe not directly relevant to the question] seem to be (though related) different measures...   thanks for your comments and answers. for historical reasons, i might leave this question instead of deleting it :).

Answer (score 3):

There [was such a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing), which [provided some feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/who-gets-the-was-this-post-useful-to-you-feedback) on what anonymous users found helpful. I think it was discontinued, and I'm not sure what was learned from it.

Comment: I believe it's actually still operational, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It must be: that page says it's gotten tens of thousands of anonymous votes today! You can see that an anonymous vote is sent to the server if you press a vote button while logged out.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - Oh, I was trying to find the "feedback" link that Jeff showed when logged out, not actually trying to vote. Didn't know that's what triggered it now.

Comment: [I mentioned the idea of using the anonymous feedback to Jon Ericson a few months back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286407/thought-experiment-what-would-happen-if-we-didnt-have-close-votes/286412#comment156963_286412) and he didn't say that it had been discontinued.

Comment: Are you saying that the "Upvote" when not logged in sends the feedback? 1. if so, is it displayed? 2. what about logged in, but reputation less than 15? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason why you need to have some rep to vote up, and there is also a reason why that count is very low. We don't need a way to bypass that, the system is working well.

Comment: As I said, I use lot of things from internet.. and from stackoverflow. I thought it will be appropriate to express my gratitude as a feedback. I guess I have to use them and not let them know that I used it...c'est la vie I guess :).