# I can't add the "okgrow" tag. Why doesn't it exist?

Tags: support, tags

In my last question, I would like to add the "okgrow" tag, but I couldn't because I have not more than 1500 reputation points.

However, you can find a real activity on GitHub: https://github.com/okgrow/analytics

Comment: Only 5 questions would  benefit: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=okgrow+is%3Aq

Comment: So, this question, which brings up a desired new tag on Meta, was closed as a duplicate of a question whose answer says to bring up a desired new tag on Meta...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan:  May make sense to reopen it then, if nothing else, to allow the facilitation of discussion for this tag.

Comment: It sounds like if you take it for granted that Stack Overflow has tags for every active github project.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work should be covering guidance, but answer to consider about 50 questions before creating tag was removed by diamond mod... Not really sure if there is better guidance when to create  tag now (starting conversation here is the right approach - so if deemed useful tag can be created as result of this post).

Comment: Thank all your comments,
@AlexeiLevenkov thank you for you link,

guys, I just asked a question sorry to disturb you ;-) 
I tried to find a similar question before to create a new question,
Why some people thinks my question is not useful ?

Comment: @DonFabiolas if you mean votes on this post - votes on meta are different and generally reflect agreement with request in the post rather than usefulness (which is very different from main SO). Indeed sometimes there are very low quality posts - but such posts will likely to be just deleted from meta rather than staying with negative vote count. You can see very popular posts with -100 votes here.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok thank you

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "votes on meta are different and generally reflect agreement with request in the post rather than usefulness" and even that is being challenged https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337486/792066

Answer (score 1):

Over the last year, as indicated by @rene in comments, there have only been 5 questions asked about the [okgrow:analytics package](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/analytics), which I'm assuming your speaking of. Before creating the tag, however, one should consider that there are actually several packages under the [okgrow](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow) moniker. Care should be taken about how to grow (sorry, couldn't resist) the tag base.

Perhaps there should be tags for each package, as in [okgrow-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okgrow-analytics), [okgroup-router-scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okgroup-router-scroll), etc.?

I personally don't know the space very well, but I'd thought I'd bring this up as something to consider for those who may create the tag(s).

Comment: Personally, I would prefer a wait and see approach instead of jumping to create a new tag. There should be someone with the required reputation that also cares to answer these questions.