# Change tooltip for up/down vote button on feature requests

Tags: bug, status-declined, voting, meta, tooltips

This is a very minor issue (and only affects SO meta), but the *feature-request* tag reads:

"On posts tagged feature-request, voting may indicate agreement or disagreement with the proposed change, in addition to the quality or usefulness of the post itself"

However the tooltip that appears when hovering over the up or downvote button on questions tagged with *feature-request* is the default one that mentions nothing about agreeing or disagreeing with a suggested feature. It also mentions "research effort" which is much more applicable to SO questions than SO meta feature-requests (in my opinion at least). Might a simple addition be in order to make this clearer?

For example on posts tagged with *feature-request* the tooltips could read something similar to the following:

---

**Upvote**: "The proposed change is clear, useful and should be implemented."

**Downvote**: "The proposed change is unclear, not useful or should not be implemented."

---

I understand that with this being such a minor change, it may not be worth going to the trouble of implementing it - but for the sake of clarity, maybe it is?

Comment: One issue is that, rightly or wrongly, voting to express disagreement sometimes happens on posts that aren't feature requests. Should we change this for Meta across the board?

Comment: I think this is a dupe of [Can we edit/remove the arrows' tooltips on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337486/can-we-edit-remove-the-arrows-tooltips-on-meta), although your feature request is a bit more specific. Still expect it to be status-declined.

Comment: @rene:  I'm as surprised as you are.

Comment: If anyone still sees this after 4 years of silence - are there any plans on addressing this or at least marking it as [meta-tag:status-deferred] or [meta-tag:status-declined]? The change would save everyone a lot of hassle in reciting the mantra "voting works differently on meta" with OPs objecting "why does the tooltip say otherwise"? If feedback on the new wording is needed, the community should be more than glad to provide it - just need to know the current status of the proposal.

Comment: I've tagged this as [status-declined], for basically the same reasons already covered in the linked MSO post, as well as the MSE post linked to in the comments there ([Change upvote/downvote tooltip on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75049/335251)). This proposes a change to the tooltip only on Meta sites, specifically posts with one particular default tag; such a narrow change is not really worth the dev time to implement and maintain.