# Why is adding tags limited to X posts at a time?

Tags: discussion, tags

With over 1700 rep points on Stack Overflow, when I need to add tags to a post, I have to submit them for review. I am a forum moderator for my company and a large set of SaaS services. Many times people forget to add the [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) platform tag to their post, which makes is more difficult for us and customers to find help that is specific to services on our platform. On occasion, I run a query to find all posts that mention IBM Cloud in them, but fail to list the [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) platform tag. When I find them, I am limited to adding the tag to about 5 at a time because the changes go into the editing queue. Should the limit be expanded perhaps when it's just tagging changes?

Note: I am not adding [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) company tag, which I don't feel necessarily has its place. But, a SaaS platform tag has its place like a product name tag.

Is there a better way to add the SaaS platform tag?

Comment: Keep on contributing and gain those last few hundreds of points to pass the 2,000 "free edits" bar. Although, even then you can but you *should* not only add these tags and ignore any and all other issues you could have fixed as well. With a certain amount of reputation, the system depends on you knowing how to behave.

Comment: please fix everything there is to fix, not just add a tag. I improved 3 of your edits and approved a fourth pending one.

Comment: For the record, I don't want to flood the queue with these types of edits and my objective is to help improve posts and the access to them. Thanks for the responses everyone! :-)

Comment: Also, there is no need to vote down a legitimate question on this forum. If you voted it down, take the time to read the "Stack Overflow Isn't Very Welcoming" blog post that is referenced to your right. Here's a PRIME example!

Comment: [Voting on Meta is different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365106/2564301). Your comment is actually a prime example for *that* question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing is actually part of the reason the suggested edit limit was created in the first place.

For a while a couple years ago, we had <2k rep users flooding the edit queue with small edits (removing only "hi" or "thanks" from posts for example) or tag only edits. Part of why this happened was that a previous reject reason, "Minor edit", was removed.

Naturally, this flooding was annoying to reviewers both because it clogged the queue, making it hard for other, more expansive edits to get through, and because *99% of the time* these edits ignored other, bigger issues.

In general, we discourage tag only edits for <2k rep users because it takes the time of *at least* two other users to get your edit through. Since others have to spend time reviewing it, we ask that you please make sure you fix everything you can with a post before you submit your edit.

> Is there a better way to add the SaaS platform tag?

Only to take your time, be sure you're editing *everything* you can in the post to make it better than when you found it. If you're taking this care, not only will you be giving reviewers a chance to clear an edit or two of yours before you submit another, but you'll also be helping improve the quality of the site. I think that's a win-win we can all get behind, really, and one you should continue once your edits no longer need reviewed just for the sake of helping improve the site.