# Edit requests should not be held to normal question standards

Tags: feature-request, edits

Currently, questions are required to include a specific ratio of code:non-code, based upon the use of "code block" formatting `like this`. This is done with the intention of limiting "code dump" posts (those with an error in the title, the entirety of someone's code, and little to no detail).

However, this is circumvented by removing "code block" formatting on the first few lines of code. An example may be this (taken from a recent question):

> //I'm learning java and i just learning something about the math class
> but i have the same error with all the methods public class Math{
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
> ```
> float num=5.45F;
>
> int result=Math.round(num);
>
> System.out.println(result); } }
> ```

Not only can this lead to confusion, as this user's error was due to non-formatted code, but also to an impossibility for editors in changing the question to be properly formatted and being given:

> It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details

I agree that posts, like those exemplified above, **are** mostly code and **should** have more detail, but that should fall upon the original asker, as opposed to editors. I don't believe that editors should be required to add context to a question, especially if that context may be incorrect or biased, to fix "code dump" type questions. That is why I am requesting that edit requests not be held to the same, automatic, standards as originally asked questions.

My suggestion would be to remove the code:non-code ratio from edit requests and give the **original asker** a message if their post violates this ratio, either before or after editing.

As a note, the example question shown above currently has the status of:

> I'm learning java and i just learning something about the math class
> but i have the same error with all the methods
>
> ```
> public class Math{
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>         float num=5.45F;
>
>         int result=Math.round(num);
>
>         System.out.println(result);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

This does fix the issue, without relying upon information inferred by editors, but I believe my reasoning still stands. I believe this because most similar "code dump but formatted to bypass automatic detection" questions do not include initial details/context in their code, and thus cannot be fixed in this way.

Comment: That question should be closed, not edited. Even if you managed to edit it, it would've either been rejected, or you would've lost the rep when (yes, when) the question gets deleted. The edit doesn't fix the critical issues with the post, hence potential rejection

Comment: @Zoe I agree that the edit does not solve the inherent issue with such questions, but wouldn't allowing edit requests to "oust" questions as code dumps serve the purpose of making code dumps easier to find and justify closure?

Comment: Not really, because questions still show up in the exact same lists and are subject to the exact same problems as all other questions. Editing doesn't speed up anything, but it does risk accidentally bumping posts into the reopen queue for no reason

Comment: "In my understanding, downvotes are intended to be used for questions that do not show any research effort; are unclear; or not useful, not for disagreement" ... to make it short, you're wrong. Voting on meta indicates dis-/agreement. That's also not new and researchable.

Comment: @Tom I am not denying that, but downvotes are not intended to be used for saying someone is wrong, unless an incorrect answer would lead the asker astray. If I am wrong, then wouldn't the correct response be to respond in a comment or answer (such as yourself and Zoe)? Unless there's some malicious flaw in my post, I don't see the justification for downvotes. I do realize that whining about downvotes goes against the selfless spirit of asking questions, but I don't understand their use in this situation.

Comment: @Tom I would advise not to lay it down as the subject being black and white, since [Meta does in fact have low quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377208/meta-does-in-fact-have-low-quality-questions). With that said, it is true that the voting culture on Meta is different, and downvotes here are often a combination of multiple factors, one of which being that users disagree with a premise or proposal.

Comment: @Tom (In response to edit) I did not realize that voting was handled differently on Meta as opposed to SO, or other SE sites. Luckily my, incorrect and somewhat whiny, addendum has been removed. For others, there is a description of my misunderstanding [here (in both the answer and the first comment)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337486/can-we-edit-remove-the-arrows-tooltips-on-meta/337520#337520), although I don't mean to imply that my post is necessarily "well formulated."

Comment: @bbnumber2 Please let the user base vote as they see fit. Putting meta-commentary complaining about downvotes is not warranted, not even on the main site. For what it's worth, there has been a suggestion to change the voting culture so that [one would express disagreement on Meta by answering the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans), but that hasn't been universally accepted.

Comment: @E_net4ofthedownvotebrigade I outlined my misunderstanding in my previous comment. Obviously I still don't want my question to be downvoted, but I understand I was incorrect in my assumptions on voting on Meta.

Comment: So user have problems getting used to this side, ok, enough are willing to help them  even when they don't get two points. so if you see soemthing that can be fixed easily arange the code and comment where the rror was or give an answer.

Comment: @bbnumber2 - If you agree the edit does not solve the inherent issue with the question.  The edit should be rejected.  I don't honestly understand what your suggestion is exactly.

Comment: @SecurityHound My suggestion was intended to serve as a method by which badly formatted posts may still be coherent without being full removed. There really isn't a point in further discussion, however. My suggestion was not well thought out and this question has been closed because of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My suggestion would be to remove the code:non-code ratio<sup>1</sup> from edit requests and give the original asker a message if their post violates this ratio, either before or after editing.

No, let's not do that. There are a few quality checks on posts and while some are notoriously stupid or massively under documented they still serve the purpose to signal to the editor that something needs more fixing then they currently did.

All users of Stack Overflow have to learn, be trained, be reminded, made aware, notice, be guided that you're blocked in completing your current task when the system thinks the content isn't up to par with the minimal quality level.

If we allowed that edit go through the content would still be bad, it would be bumped on the active list where it attracts new eyes that still see a badly formatted post, reviewers get confused as why that edit was made and even worse, if the question was closed already, a bad edit would put it in the re-open queue where it would be rejected if it wasn't edited into shape. When the proper edit is made the question isn't for a second time submitted for a re-open review. So now you only can rely on tag followers.

I have the impression your request is geared towards optimizing a sub optimal workflow / user experience for an editor. I doubt we need to optimize the system for that. We have plenty of other editors and other mechanisms in place to achieve what you couldn't at this stage. That doesn't need to be unblocked because we don't want subpar edits to enter the system.

If you run into this, leave a comment to explain the issue. Either the OP or a user with full edit privileges might come along and edit the post into shape. Thank you for assisting in improving the content quality.

---

1. it is not a ratio. It is a regex that checks for certain symbol characters that are present in the body that don't sit in a code block. One misplaced / # or ( can already trip it.