# Problem when editing a post: Properly inserting code fails

Tags: feature-request, bug

I was doing some review in the "First Post"-Queue, when I stumbled across this post, where a user asked a question about some long error. I saw that he mistakenly used this token: `'` instead of the correct `

This happened to me too when I was new to the site, so I tried to edit his post accordingly. I replaced the triple ' with a triple ` , but when I tried to save, this happenes:

[image]

I guess that is correct, and I would have flagged the post as "Needs details" after proposing the edit, to make the post at least readable, but now I can't submit what I feel is a substantial improvement in readability.

I'd suggest, that the check for "mostly code" is disable during review edits, it's not the editors fault that some users fail to provide more detail in their questions. Still I tried to make the post at least readable, before voting to close it. Another idea is to just discourage people to use triple `'''` in their code and to specifically warn them, before they can submit the code. The optical difference between ' and ` is quite small, and I think it could help so that issues like this one don't occur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit requests should not be held to normal question standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399038/edit-requests-should-not-be-held-to-normal-question-standards) (note that the _actual_ request is the same: *"remove the code:non-code ratio from edit requests"*)

Comment: You are right, flagging (for "Needs debugging details") is the correct action. Please don't edit off-topic posts if your edit doesn't make the post on-topic. You are just wasting the time of the reviewers in this case.

Comment: It does @Nick. I forgot about the reviewers of the edits, so I guess just straightforward flagging would have been the correct action to take.